# Is there a way to make cmakelists.txt more verbose for compilation

Tags: debian, compiling, cmake

Many a times while compiling some binary or library, I feel a need to have much verbose output of the build/compilation. Is there a flag or something I can write in the cmakelists.txt so I get much more verbose output. FWIW, I'm using cmake 3.16.3 on Debian testing which will eventually become Debian bullseye. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When running `cmake` itself, there are a couple of options you can use to generate more detailed output:

```
cmake --debug-output
```

and

```
cmake --trace
```

(the latter with even more detail than the former).

When running the build, you can ask for a verbose build by running

```
make VERBOSE=1
```

or at the `cmake` stage, define `CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE`:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON
```

(which is what `debhelper` does by default when using `cmake`).